# ASP.NET Conflict in implementing javascript through masterpage hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dialog, asp.net-4.0

I am using master page in implementing all my content page. So the header includes a hyperlink which called `Feedback`. Of course, this hyperlink repeated every page. The Javascript code is in the master page as bellow:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#hlfeedback').click(function () {
            var dlg = jQuery('div#message').dialog({
                width: 608,
                height: 750,
                modal: true,
                overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 },
                buttons: {},
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                }
            });
            dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        });
    });

    </script>
```

The question is should I put the `div#message` in every content page? and the asp.net server side as well? btw when i put the div#message in the master page only, it doesn't work.

Help me please.

Comment: No errors. I want to simplify the process and make it easier with less codes. if possible of course.

Comment: so what is the problem...

Comment: I have around 100 content pages. Is there any solution rather than writing the DIV and the server side asp.net codes in all my pages? using maybe shortcut or something related to the masterpage

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but using master page means, that your server controls get ID like this:

## cphBody_"your_serverside_id" (or Title, Head and etc.)